# Rendering Database view in dataTables Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rails-activerecord

Based on a table `employees`, I created a view in my MySQL database called `Employees_by_gender`:

```
select count(gender_id) AS "Number of Employees",gender_id AS "Gender" from employees group by gender_id;

mysql> select * from Employee_by_gender;
+--------+---------------------+
| Gender | Number of Employees |
+--------+---------------------+
|      1 |                3890 |
|      2 |                1087 |
+--------+---------------------+
```

How do I render the output of this database view in a client side table? I've been using "dataTables bootstrap rails" for all my normal tables rendering.

[image: Screenshot of table]

How can I get this data in a table-like display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure on the specifics of dataTables, but you can create an ActiveRecord model for the view as if it were a normal (read-only) table:

```
class EmployeesByGender < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name 'Employees_by_gender'
end
```

However, you are going to have a very hard time unless you rename your view column names to not contain spaces.

If you must keep the spaces in the column names, follow the advise here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.lang.ruby/SNZNQu_h92w

Comment: You are wonderful sir :D ...
Just i had to add = sign 
`code`
    class EmployeesByGender < ActiveRecord::Base
      self.table_name = 'Employees_by_gender'
    end

it when started working ...

also i made new views removig all white spaces :)...

Answer (score 0):

Try look this [Railscasts #340 datables](http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables)... Hope it helps. The implementation its very straightforward.